# Can somebody help me. I've sent my BNB contribution to the token contract address (0x5132e359C9E784e339F803B9b73895335f3387cf) instead of the presale

Tags: bsc

Please help me as the team says they cant transfer the funds back to my wallet yet I've checked that they have a transfer function. Thank you so much

Comment: This is a question for Binance support, not for a public forum.Binance is a commercial operation with a help desk and also power to help you. No one here can help you. Contact Binance support.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I read through their entire contract and there is no way to get stuck tokens out of the main contract. They there was a hope in the *swapAndLiquify* function but it subtracts the initial balance thus making the BNB stuck.

If I were auditing I would advise the team to add a function to take stuck tokens from the contract or fuse the with liquidity.

Comment: Any possible recommendation to the team so I can take back my Beans? Or there is no way at all?

Comment: Unfortunately no, any funds received would be on the goodness of the team.

Comment: Can BSC Scan team help in any way?